# How to change selected option element between 2 selectbox in select2 in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need change selected between two select2 with jQuery.

For Example:

```
<select id="fromCity" class="select2">
    <option value='THR' selected> Tehran </option>
    <option value='LON'> London </option>
</select>
```

And

```
<select id="toCity" class="select2">
    <option value='THR'> Tehran </option>
    <option value='LON' selected> London </option>
</select>
```

Now, I need after click **THR -> LON** change to **LON -> THR**

In jQuery:

```
$('i[data-change-airport]').on('click', function () {
    var fromCity = $('#fromCity').val();
    var toCity = $('#toCity').val();

    $('#fromCity').select2('val', toCity);
    $('#toCity').select2('val', fromCity);
})
```

But this code not work. Where is problem?

Comment: which select2 version you are using ? are you getting fromCity and toCity values in console ?

Comment: Hi @rahul_m, I don't now select2 version. yes, i get fromCity and toCity in console and true.

Comment: once check alternative way, I gave in my answer, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using one of latest versions > 4.0,

Then try this,

```
$('i[data-change-airport]').on('click', function () {
    var fromCity = $('#fromCity').val();
    var toCity = $('#toCity').val();
    $('#fromCity').val(toCity).trigger("change");
    $('#toCity').val(fromCity).trigger("change"); 
});
```

Give it a try, it should work.

if still doesn't work,
you can try one more alternative

```
$('#fromCity').val(toCity).trigger('change.select2');
$('#toCity').val(fromCity).trigger('change.select2');
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.select2').on('change', function() {
  $('.select2').not(this).val($(this).val());
  $('.select2').not(this).val($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fromCity" class="select2">
    <option value='THR' selected> Tehran </option>
    <option value='LON'> London </option>
</select> And

<select id="toCity" class="select2">
    <option value='THR'> Tehran </option>
    <option value='LON' selected> London </option>
</select>
```

Try this way

Comment: Hi, Thank you for help me, but i need change airport after click ;-)